# Unable to view message in Sitecore 7.2 ECM

Tags: ecm

I am getting error as `Connection refused to remote server` while accessing message in Email Campaign Manager.

I was trying to test by `sitecore/admin/ECM.requestbody.aspx` where it's connecting to wrong rendering URL which got modified when we moved our server to `https`.

I modified the Rendering URL field manually and clicked on 'Check'. Now I get  Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

So, I navigated to `System/Email Campaign Manager/GlobalSettings` to configure Rendering URL field. But I don't see that field there. Do I have to upgrade `ECM` version to configure Rendering URL field.

Am I going in right direction? Please give me some input in resolving this.

Answer (score 2):

> **Version Note:** This answer applies to EXM 3.5 or Sitecore 9.X only.

You can configure `EXM.RendererUrl` in the `Sitecore.EmailExperience.Core.config` config file.

In case the setting is empty, the `RendererUrl` is resolved on the first request to the application. In the `<httpRequestBegin>` pipeline, there is a `Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.OnHttpRequestBegin` processor that that does that:

```
GlobalSettings.RendererUrl = WebUtil.GetServerUrl(args.HttpContext.Request.Url, false);
```

You said that it worked ok previously on HTTP, but after you switched to HTTPS, it does not work. First I would focus on fixing the SSL/TLS issue. I bet that there is some problem with the certificate.

Comment: After moving to https hostname has been changed and we are using old ECM version only still. So, I assuming some settings issue only. Because after moving to https all other things are working fine except ECM. Any idea why Rendering URL field is not shown in Email Campaign Manager -> Settings -> Global Settings item?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @bartłomiej-mucha is true for version 3.5 and above. In older versions of EXM (and ECM) you have to resort to implementing an extension as explained in [Customize the Renderer URL setting in ECM](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/837879):

> To be able to specify the Renderer URL manually, you can implement a
>   small extension.
>
> Check the following example:
>
> Create a custom processor to update the Renderer URL with the value
>   from a configuration file. For example:
>
> ```
> public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
> {
>   Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.GlobalSettings.RendererUrl = Settings.GetSetting("ECM.RendererUrl");
> }
> ```
>
> Add this processor to the  pipeline of the web.config:
>
> ```
> <pipelines>
>   <initialize>
>     ...
>     <processor type="<your-processor-class-name, your-assembly" />
>   </initialize>
> ```
>
> Specify the required value of the ECM.RendererUrl setting in the
>   web.config. This address should be accessible from the ECM server
>   (where the message is being created and dispatched) of your Sitecore
>   environment:
>
> ```
> <settings>
>   ...
>   <setting name="ECM.RendererUrl" value="http://yourhost" />
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this. Any idea under which namespace GlobalSettings come under? or I have to fetch 'System/Email Campaign Manager/GlobalSettings ' and update?

Comment: @user8927358 Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign

Comment: Able to set the rendering Url with above steps. Thank you for the help :)